# Why doesn't the upcase! method work on an string?

Tags: ruby

The bang method doesn't substitute in-place as I'd expect:

```
2.0.0p247 :010 > string = "abc"
 => "abc" 
2.0.0p247 :011 > string[2]
 => "c" 
2.0.0p247 :012 > string[2].upcase!
 => "C" # so far so good...
2.0.0p247 :013 > string
 => "abc" # expected "abC"
2.0.0p247 :014 > string[2]
 => "c" # expected "C"
```

Why is this, and how should I up-case a character in a string by index in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: See explanations on [this stackoverflow post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931810/string-destructive-methods-dont-seem-to-work-on-string-slice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string[2]` returns a new string which is upcased and discarded. You should assign it back to the string.

```
string = "abc"
string[2] = string[2].upcase
string # => "abC"
```

Comment: surprisingly verbose for ruby, but thanks a lot works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`string[2]` returns a string. That string is `upcase!`d in-place. However, since that string is not referenced anywhere, you will never notice.

```
tmp = ObjectSpace.each_object(String).to_a

string = 'abc'
string[2].upcase!

ObjectSpace.each_object(String).to_a - tmp
# => ['C']
```

As you can see, the string *was* in fact allocated somewhere within the garbage collector, it just isn't accessible from anywhere, because there is no reference to it.