# String destructive methods don't seem to work on string slice

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string and I want to capitalize the first letter. I tried the following:

```
x='abc'
x[0].upcase! # => "A"
x # => "abc"
```

It doesn't work as intended, even though the method `upcase!` is destructive. The following works:

```
x='abc'
x[0] = x[0].upcase # => "A"
x # => "Abc"
```

Can someone explain why `upcase!` doesn't work above?

Comment: When you get a string slice this way, the slice is copied and new string is created.

Comment: Not directly answering your question you can also try using the [capitalize](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21) method. `x = "abc" ; x.capitalize! #=>'Abc'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x[0]` is returning a new string. You are modifying this new string in place and then you do nothing with it.

Note:

You can use the `capitalize` method to do the same:

```
x='abc'
x.capitalize!
x    #=> 'Abc'
```

Comment: Thank you.  x[0] is returning a new string.  But how does x[0] = x[0].upcase change x, if x[0] is a new string?  This is because []= is a method on String class. The Ruby doc on String class regarding "[]=" states "Element Assignment—Replaces some or all of the content of str."

Answer (score 2):

`upcase!` is destructive, and it modifies the string `x[0]`, but not `x`. You haven't done anything to `x` with `upcase!`.

Comment: But isn't `x[0]` a part of `x`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - it is not. It is a substring of `x` and apart of its origin it has nothing in common with `x`.

Comment: @BroiSatse: I know it, obviously. :) I was just pointing out lack of explanation in sawa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a different string object. You can find out if you use `object_id` on your objects and compare them.